# write to make a custom function in google spreadsheet to find the user by the user email in the user tab

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Thanks in advanc.I tried my best but not got success.Please any expert can help me.
write a custom function in google spreadsheet to find the user by the user email in the user tab.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Google Developers Official Link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions).

Custom Function :

```
function customFunctionName(arg1, arg2, ..., argN) {
  // The code for your custom function goes here
  ...
  // The value you return here will be displayed in the cell in the Spreadsheet
  // in which the custom function is entered
  return someValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on the structure of your sheet, take this as an example:

```
function selectUsers() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YOURFILEID');
  var name = spreadsheet.getName();
  Logger.log('spread name '+name);
  var usersSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Users');
  name = usersSheet.getName();
  Logger.log('usersSheet name '+name);
  var rows = usersSheet.getRange(3,3, 15, 5);//depends on the actual size of your data
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  Logger.log('numRows ' + numRows);
  var emails = [];
  var values = rows.getValues();
  for (var row in values) {
    var email = values[row][1];//depends on which column you used for email, this example the 2nd.
    emails.push(email);
  }
}
```

Comment: please can you tell me how It will call. Please tell me in details

Comment: I means How I can call this function ?

Comment: Save it as a google script .gs then from https://script.google.com open it and from the menu RUN there should be the selectUsers

Comment: Can I add interface ui icon on spreedsheet as summation symbal

Comment: You need to add an Add-on for that http://googledrive.blogspot.com/2014/03/add-ons.html